# What is the equation used with duct sizing charts?

Tags: hvac

What is the equation used with duct sizing charts?

I can look at duct sizing charts and they're all the same so if I point to as an example:
https://hvacdirect.com/hvac/pdf/Field_duct-sizing-chart.pdf you can see it too.

However if I try to figure how these numbers for volume of air per size of duct were calculated my math is not making sense.

As an example, if I want to verify the cfm of the 8" duct I would use the formula 3.14 x r squared x the velocity of the air / 144" or the square foot in inches. This does not correlate to the numbers found in the chart, why?

Either my math is wrong or my understanding of what the air flow is.

The velocity I am using is 800 fpm based on what is a good velocity for a branch which is between 700 and 1000 fpm. So, I went with a middle norm, 800 fpm. But the velocity I come up with when trying to figure out how the duct sizing charts get there numbers is around 450 fpm.

Me - 8" duct 3.14 x 4 x 4 x 800 / 144 = 279 cfm
chart reads - 8" is 160 cfm

and to find velocity of the chart at 160 cfm
144 * 160 \ 3.14 x 4 x 4 = 459 fpm

459 fpm for the charts and 700 - 1000 fpm is recommended. I am not sure why the discrepancy. Any help?

Comment: velocity minus friction loss which increases with distance and likely assumes bends

Comment: air velocity in the ducts is calculated by dividing airflow by duct cross-section.

Comment: You're right that velocity times sectional area will give you flow rate.  But where are you getting the velocity you're using to calculate flow rate?

Comment: @WilliamWarren where did you get the 700-1000 fpm?  (Also, your units should be fpm, not fps.)

Comment: @Huesmann I read around and seen these number thrown about most the time. If you do a google search for "duct work best velocity" you should find several sites that state the same or nearly the same. However, the algorithm tied to each of us can be severely different in results so a look at cedengineering.com is one example.

Comment: @Huesmann About the fpm fps, that is a typo I will now correct. Thanks for the heads up. If you look at the beginning of the post you will see I started using the fpm notation then slipped at the ending of the post by stating fps. I am going  to delete this comment once I know you have read it.